# i want to bulid a mpop function that that delete the given index . but it showing SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to implement `Stack` as following

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def mypop(self,items):

        self.items=items

        n= del items[len(self.items)]

        return n

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

s=Stack()

print("Empty: ", s.isEmpty())
s.push(4)
s.push('dog')
print("Peek: ", s.peek())
s.push(True)
print("Size: ", s.size())
print("Empty: ", s.isEmpty())
s.push(8.4)
print(s.items)
print("Pop: ", s.mypop())
print("Pop: ", s.mypop())
print("Size: ", s.size())
```

I want to build  a mpop function that that delete the given index  but it showing

```
n= del items[len(self.items)]
```

It gives error showing while assigning the items here
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

The `del`  function doesn't return the item it removes only. [see the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement). So, the `SyntaxError` in your code as you are trying to assign. Use `pop` instead, it returns the element

```
#your code
def mypop(self):
    n = self.items.pop()
    return n
#your code
```